# Drag and Drop controls Tablelayoutpanels retain the controls instead refreshing

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

```
    Dim dragLVI As ListViewItem

    ' get text and do whatever with it
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(ListViewItem)) = False) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        Exit Sub
    Else
        dragLVI = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(ListViewItem)),
                                       ListViewItem)


        AnotherLabel.Name = AnotherLabel.ToString
        AnotherLabel.Text = dragLVI.SubItems(0).Text
        AnotherLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        AnotherLabel.Parent = tblInvoicing

        'Define Point

        Dim loc As Point = Me.tblInvoicing.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))

        'detemine the cell location

        Dim ColumnIndex As Integer = -1

        Dim RowIndex As Integer = -1

        Dim x As Integer = 0

        Dim y As Integer = 0


        While ColumnIndex <= Me.tblInvoicing.ColumnCount

            If loc.X < x Then


                Exit While
            End If

            ColumnIndex += 1


            x += Me.tblInvoicing.GetColumnWidths()(ColumnIndex)
        End While

        While RowIndex <= Me.tblInvoicing.RowCount

            If loc.Y < y Then


                Exit While
            End If

            RowIndex += 1


            y += Me.tblInvoicing.GetRowHeights()(RowIndex)
        End While



        tblInvoicing.Controls.Add(AnotherLabel, ColumnIndex, RowIndex)
```

As I drag an item in listview and drop from Tablelayoutpanel, it only accepts one control only. How to retain the controls everytime I drop another control; I've already research a lot of information regarding that but still no luck.

Thanks for anyone who can answer.

Comment: That is because you only use one control.  There is only "AnotherLabel", you just move it around.  Use the `New` operator to create a new label.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry for a very long delay reply, yes I've solved that by moving the AnotherLabel variable.